# Executing stored procedure with input param in C#

Tags: c#, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am having trouble executing a stored procedure supplying string value for a input param that is of type nvarchar(128). The param in question is 'username' . As per the proc definition is nvarchar(128) please look at screenshot#2. Below is my C# code where am setting the parameters

```
if (StoredProcedureExists(auditStoredProc, localConnString))
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlCommand auditCommand = new SqlCommand("sp_executesql", localConnection, tran))
        {
            auditCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            auditCommand.CommandTimeout = sqlCommandTimeoutFallbackValue;
            auditCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stmt", auditStoredProc);
            var userNameParam = auditCommand.CreateParameter();
            userNameParam.ParameterName = "@username";
            userNameParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
            userNameParam.Value = "JQS";
            auditCommand.Parameters.Add(userNameParam);

            //my custom method to show what command will be executed
            var commnd = CommandAsSql(auditCommand);

            auditCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

The command execution query built by the code is

```
use my_db_name_here;
declare @return_value int;
exec [sp_executesql]
@stmt = 'dbo.pr_kr_AuditSetUserName', 
@username = 'JQS';
select 'Return Value' = convert(varchar, @return_value);
```

When it executes, the exception I see is

> 'Incorrect Syntax near JQS'

Full Exception message:
        e = {"Incorrect syntax near 'JQS'."}

> "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near 'JQS'.\r\n 
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection,
>   Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)\r\n
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)\r\n
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj,
>   Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)\r\n
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler,
>   SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj,
>   Boolean& dataReady)\r\n
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption,
>   Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)\r\n
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, 
>   Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, 
>   Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)\r\n
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, 
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion,
>   Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)\r\n
>
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion,
>   String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, 
>   Boolean inRetry)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()\r\n 
>   at Endpoint.JQS.Common.Processor.ProcessJob(JobQueueMessage message) 
>   in C:\dev\Endpoint.JQS\Endpoint.JQS.Common\Processor.cs:line 92\r\n
>   ClientConnectionId:39dbe3e4-8b0e-4d23-8b13-2bc379313328\r\n
>   Error Number:102,State:1,Class:15"

**NOTE:**
Ln#92 in the error message is the line that calls to auditCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

Stored procedure dbo.pr_kr_AuditSetUserName definition is below
[image: input parameter type]
[image: proc definition]

Comment: Paste code(text) not pictures.

Comment: Post the *actual code*, not images of the code that can't be copied or compiled. ADO.NET doesn't create strings either. What does `CommandAsSql` do and why is it used *at all* instead of simply calling `ExecuteNonQuery`?

Comment: Post the full exception, including the call stack too. You can get that easily with `Exception.ToString()`. Don't post parts of it. This will tell you (and us) on which line the exception was thrown, which function threw it etc. Right now we don't even know if this is a C# or SQL message

Comment: updated the code instead of screenshot.

Comment: If you want to run a stored procedure just pass it's name as the query. Don't try to execute `sp_executesql`. You should have written `new SqlCommand("pr_kr_AuditSetUserName",...`

Comment: Explain the down vote, pls its as comprehensive as possible

Comment: @theandroid why do you call `sp_executesql` at all?

Comment: @theandroid not my downvote but no, it's not comprehensive. It contains screenshots, the exception is missing and the code is unusual to say the least. I suspect you encountered an error when you tried to execute the stored procedure in the normal way and assumed that somehow you need to use `sp_executesql`? You don't, and that won't fix the original error

Comment: tried executing the stored procedure directly instead of the sp_executesql, that produces the same sql error

Comment: @theandroid what same error? Post the original code, and **full** information

Comment: @theandroid I'll repeat it, post the *full exception text*, not just parts of it. Don't copy it from the debug window, the exception dialog box even has a `copy button`. Don't force people to format your code just to read it

Comment: updated with full error message.

Comment: @BWA: Explain the down vote please, I have replaced the code snippet screenshot with the code and updated the exception to show the full message. Kindly reconsider.

Comment: Why should I explain the down vote if I didn't give it to you? I was just suggesting  pasting text not pictures.

Comment: You haven't posted any new C# code that doesn't attempt to use sp_executeSql.   Is that because you haven't attempted it yet?   That is the beginning of the solution.   There are other problems as well.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the "sp_execute_sql" with the stored procedure name itself. That also removes the need to pass the stored proc name in @stmt parameter. The working code is below.

```
try
{
  using (SqlCommand auditCommand = new SqlCommand(
                                         auditStoredProc,
                                         localConnection,
                                         tran))
  {
     auditCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     auditCommand.CommandTimeout = sqlCommandTimeoutFallbackValue;
     var userNameParam = auditCommand.CreateParameter();
     userNameParam.ParameterName = "@username";
     userNameParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
     userNameParam.Value = "JobQueueService";
     auditCommand.Parameters.Add(userNameParam);
     auditCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   Logger.Error("Error executing audit storedprocedure" + e.ToString());                                            
}
```